# pip not installing existing package

Tags: python, installation, pip, spacy

I'm trying to install `spacy 2.1.0` using `pip`. However, I'm running into an issue where I get an error message stating that

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement spacy==2.1.0 
(from versions: 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.40, 0.51, 0.52, 0.60, 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.67, 0.68, 0.70, 
0.80, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.90, 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.97, 
0.98, 0.99, 0.100.0, 0.100.1, 0.100.2, 0.100.3, 0.100.4, 0.100.5, 0.100.6, 0.100.7, 0.101.0, 1.0.1, 
1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 
1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.5, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 2.0.0, 
2.0.1.dev0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2.dev0, 2.0.2, 2.0.3.dev0, 2.0.3, 2.0.4.dev0, 2.0.4, 2.0.5.dev0, 2.0.5, 
2.0.6.dev0, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.0.10.dev0, 2.0.10, 2.0.11.dev0, 2.0.11, 2.0.12.dev0, 
2.0.12.dev1, 2.0.12, 2.0.13.dev0, 2.0.13.dev1, 2.0.13.dev2, 2.0.13.dev4, 2.0.13, 2.0.14.dev0, 
2.0.14.dev1, 2.0.15, 2.0.16.dev0, 2.0.16, 2.0.17.dev0, 2.0.17.dev1, 2.0.17, 2.0.18.dev0, 
2.0.18.dev1, 2.0.18, 2.1.0, 2.1.1.dev0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.7.dev0, 
2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.2.0.dev10, 2.2.0.dev11, 2.2.0.dev13, 2.2.0.dev15, 2.2.0.dev17, 
2.2.0.dev18, 2.2.0.dev19, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2.dev0, 2.2.2.dev4, 2.2.2, 2.2.3.dev0, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 
2.3.0.dev1, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3.dev0, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 3.0.0, 3.0.1.dev0, 3.0.1, 
3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for spacy==2.1.0
```

I find this weird because it says that it searched through version 2.1.0 (11th line of the message), but it still didn't detect it.

My version of pip has the latest update. I'm working in a virtual environment. I'm on macOS Big Sur Version 11.1. I'm using `Python 3.8.3`. To reproduce the error, set up a clear virtual environment with the latest version of `pip 21.1`, run `pip install spacy==2.1.0`. Then, after waiting for some time, the error message should pop up.

I'm unsure why this message seems to be happening as it knows that `spacy 2.1.0` exists. I've had this error with other packages too, such as `scikit-learn`. I've also attempted installing directly from a `tar.gz` file to no avail. Then, I get an error that it `exited with status 1`. Nevertheless, if you all have any solutions on how I can succesfully install this version of `spacy`, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Also, I'm kinda new to posting on stack**overflow**, so if there is anything that is missing from my message that would help you, don't hesitate to let me know. Thanks :D

Comment: Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: `Python` 3.8.3. Added to original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from @RMPR is a good suggestion in general, but I suspect you're still going to run into problems with the required version of the dependency `blis`, which has some out-dated/hacky OS X settings that are probably the source of the original install error.

Run the following to see if there is an error towards the end about mismatched `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` versions (it will take a few minutes to get that far; you can stop the command as soon as you see this error):

```sh
python -m pip install blis==0.2.4
```

The error looks like this:

```
  error: $MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET mismatch: now "10.7" but "10.14.6" during configure
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
```

`10.7` is the out-dated hard-coded default from `blis==0.2.4`, so set it to the right value from the error message. In my example, this worked:

```sh
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.14.6" python -m pip install spacy==2.1.0
```

(Caveat: I could only test this in emulation mode on an M1.)

Comment: Sorry for testing this late; however, I followed this and it worked! I now have spacy v2.1.0 downloaded in my environment. Thank you a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [wheels on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/spacy/#files) it seems like there are no build currently for macosx 11 (Big Sur) the closest is [this one](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/97/4cac1c4ac95af031b627968120bf273193e2f2134ff01b069cf630414272/spacy-3.0.6-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl) that you can install by using:

```
pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/97/4cac1c4ac95af031b627968120bf273193e2f2134ff01b069cf630414272/spacy-3.0.6-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
```

But you should get an error message stating that the wheel is not supported on the platform. And that's probably why even though pip listed the version of the library you still got that error message. You either have to downgrade to a supported macOS version or [install from source](https://pypi.org/project/spacy/) (instructions on how to install the v2.1.0 below).

You need to first install a recent version of XCode, including the "Command Line Tools" then:

```
git clone https://github.com/explosion/spaCy
cd spaCy

python -m venv .env
source .env/bin/activate

# make sure you are using the latest pip
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools wheel

# checkout to the desired version of spaCy
git checkout v2.1.0

pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install --no-build-isolation --editable .
```

Comment: Sorry I tested this late. I have tried it out, and I got a similar error to the one I described in my post. However, @aab had the solution I needed. Nevertheless, thank you for your time and help! It is greatly appreciated :D